# Multiple domains (including www-"subdomain") on apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, domain

after messing around a while I decided to ask here:

I have a vhost and want to use 2 domains on this server. My apache configuration file looks something like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName www.domain1.de   
    DocumentRoot /var/www/folder1/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName www.domain2.de
    DocumentRoot /var/www/folder2/
</VirtualHost>
```

On the configuration page for the domains of my vhost both domains assigned to the server ip.

The problem now is:

- www.domain1.de works
- domain1.de works
- www.domain2.de works
- domain2.de does **not** work

Has any one any idee why the second domain only works with the added "www"?

Comment: how's your dns configured - does it resolve both domain2.de  and www.domain2.de to the same ip ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`domain1.de` works because `www.domain1.de` is the first `VirtualHost` and is served as default. You need to add `ServerAlias domain2.de` to `www.domain2.de` for the shorter version to work as well (you should add `ServerAlias` for `www.domain1.de` too).

If you don't want `www.domain1.de` to be served as default add another `VirtualHost` at the begining serving some simple HTML file.

Comment: 1000 x tnx! as usual a very simple solution.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to canonicalize your domains (e.g. redirect all domain.de to www.domain.de) you can use something like mod_rewrite:

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName www.domain.de
  ServerAlias domain.de

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
  RewriteRule /(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

The three Rewrite lines will basically:

1. Check to see if the URL starts with 'www'
2. If not, redirect to http://www.domain.de/[whatever]

If you go to 'domain.de' it will see that it doesn't start with 'www' and redirect to 'www.domain.de'.

If you want to apply this to every site you host, you can do like this:

```
<VirtualHost *>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
  RewriteRule /(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName www.domain1.de
  DocumentRoot /wherever/1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName www.domain2.de
  DocumentRoot /wherever/2
</VirtualHost>
```

Then when someone tries to go to 'domain1.de' it will hit the first virtualhost, which will redirect them automatically to 'www.[whatever domain they typed in]'.

This way, if you go to 'domain1.de' it will see that it doesn't start with 'www' and redirect to 'www.domain1.de'. For 'domain2.de', it will redirect to 'www.domain2.de'. Every time you add a new site, you will automatically get this feature, which can be really handy if you're adding/maintaining a lot of websites.

Answer (score 1):

www.domain.com and domain.com can theoretically be entirely different websites. You must specify both. You could use a ServerAlias in your existing VirtualHost blocks, or, you could do this to do a 301 Redirect for SEO.

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName domain1.de  
    DocumentRoot /var/www/folder1/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName www.domain1.de  
    Redirect permanent / http://domain1.de/ 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName domain2.de  
    DocumentRoot /var/www/folder2/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName www.domain2.de  
    Redirect permanent / http://domain2.de/ 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This is a messy and complicated solution that doesn't make a whole lot of sense. You could use something like a mod_rewrite snippet to check for 'www' at the start and redirect if not. Otherwise your apache config balloons and it becomes easy to miss things or typo.

Comment: Rewrite rules would be three extra lines (engine on, condition, and rule) per domain, this is four. I fail to see how it's particularly messy or complicated in comparison, especially if you do what most people do and have each domain's vhosts in its own .conf file.

Comment: see @Dan Udey's answer

Answer (score 1):

Use ServerAlias to associate more than 1 domain to a virtual host

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName www.domain1.de 
    ServerAlias domain1.de *.domain1.de  
    DocumentRoot /var/www/folder1/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName www.domain2.de
    ServerAlias domain2.de *.domain2.de  
    DocumentRoot /var/www/folder2/
</VirtualHost>
```