# Subdomain on apache

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain

I'm looking at something like this:
[Multiple domains (including www-"subdomain") on apache?](https://serverfault.com/questions/22632/multiple-domains-including-www-subdomain-on-apache)

And I'm too dumb to figure out how to get 1 subdomain to direct to 1 place.

I need

phpmyadmin.site.com/

to go to

/vol/www/phpMyAdmin

```
# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost phpmyadmin.site.com

<VirtualHost phpmyadmin.site.com>
DocumentRoot /vol/www/phpMyAdmin
ServerName phpmyadmin.site.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

just goes to site.com (i've restarted)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample:

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName phpmyadmin.site.com
    DocumentRoot /vol/www/phpMyAdmin
    <Directory "/vol/www/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This means receive requests to any ip (`*`)
This virtual host exists on all ips (`*`)

It responds to the request using ServerName in the URI
and it serves from the DocumentRoot specified

Make sure you have the `<directory>` directive too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is excerpt from my apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@xxx.com
    ServerName  xxx.com
    ServerAlias www.xxx.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/htdocs/xxx.com
    ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/xxx.com-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/xxx.com-access_log combined

   <Directory "/srv/www/htdocs/xxx.com">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  phpMyAdmin.xxx.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/htdocs/xxx.com/phpMyAdmin
    ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/phpMyAdmin.xxx.com-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/phpMyAdmin.xxx.com-access_log combined

   <Directory "/srv/www/htdocs/ccc.com/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```