# Subdomain returns error when restarting Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, subdomain

I try to install a subdomain on my dedicated server. I made a new DNS rules to point my sub domain to the IP of my serv.

After reading this [Subdomain on apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/105942/subdomain-on-apache) i tried to add new rules on Apache :

```
NameVirtualHost IP:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /home/www/mysite/tb
ServerName tb.mysite.org
</VirtualHost>
```

Then i restart Apache but it returns

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2 
 [Wed Jun 27 12:33:41 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts                                                                                                                                                    
 ... waiting [Wed Jun 27 12:33:42 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

the tb/ folder is existing, don't why Apache can't find it... And it says that NameVirtualHost:80 has no VirtualHosts...

**EDIT :** Here is my complete /etc/apache2/sites-available/default http://pastebin.com/ZzVBFQvX
Hop it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Show the output of this:
    ls -dl /home/mysite/wwww/tb

> And it says that NameVirtualHost:80 has no VirtualHosts...

Try to change to `NameVirtualHost <IP>:80`

Comment: i try to put NameVirtualHost 88.191.XXX.XXX:80 instead of NameVirtualHost *:80 but it still returns `NameVirtualHost 88.191.XXX.XXX:80 has no VirtualHosts`

Comment: The `DocumentRoot [/home/mysite/wwww/tb/] does not exist` is fixed btw

Answer (score 0):

Does the user your Apache server runs as have permission to view /home/mysite/wwww/tb/? If the folder exists, but the user the apache server runs as does not haver permission to read it, then as far as apache is concerned, it does not exist.